# D-Link DIR-300 with DD-WRT, doesn't handle more than few devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I've got a problem with my home router, D-Link DIR-300 with DD-WRT. It seems that for some reason it cannot handle more than few devices connected at the same time on wireless network. The maximum is around 5, but I couldn't pinpoint it to a single number—it seems that sometimes 6 or 7 could be connected at the same time.

I found this only when my family got more WiFi-capable devices; currently those are: 3 smartphones, 3 notebooks and a WiFi-capable printer. In addition to that, there's a one device (a desktop PC) on an Ethernet cable.

When the supposed maximum is reached, the network is still visible (as in: when scanning for WiFi networks, the name is still visible on any device that is not connected), but an attempt to connect to the network ends in failure, usually with no specific message shown. However when I temporarily disconnect a second device manually, the first device can connect without troubles.

It looks the same with any device: I've seen the printer, any of the mobiles and any of the notebooks failing to connect to the network because of that.

I don't know how to debug the problem further. Is that an inherent limitation of the device, or maybe just a misconfiguration on the router side? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the maximum number of DHCP users that is set in DD-WRT? (that setting is somewhere under DHCP, possibly below the starting address for the DHCP range).

Comment: @lupincho: 50 (“fifty”).

Comment: is there an ip range? eg: 192.168.1.2 through 192.168.1.7? If so, increase the 2nd value to something high, such as 192.168.1.49. (This happened to me before, and that was why)

Comment: @Blaine: DHCP uses a range of 192.168.0.100÷200.

Comment: have you tried doing a factory reset?

Comment: @Blaine: yes, I did. No change.